# Build Failed, Missing Key Attribute (Android SDK)

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I recently imported my project over from Eclipse ADT over to Android SDK. I'm trying to re-run my simulator but I am encountering a problem with my AndroidManifest.xml file which states: `/Users/####/Documents/android/medicine/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:13:13-30 Error: Missing one of the key attributes 'action#name,category#name' on element intent-filter at AndroidManifest.xml:13:13-30`

I searched on Google for the error but haven't come up with anything solid. Is there a reason for this error, I am assuming it is because of the Android version? Any help on this would be great.

Below is my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="20101" android:versionName="2.1.1" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.medicine" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="Med Finder">
   <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="Medicine" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="org.pgsqlite.SQLitePlugin">
        <intent-filter />
    </activity>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.ads.conversiontracking.InstallReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.medicine.MESSAGE" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <receiver
android:name="com.pushbots.google.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
    <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name="com.medicinefinder" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
 <receiver android:name="com.pushbots.push.DefaultPushHandler" />
 <service android:name="com.pushbots.push.GCMIntentService" />
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
 <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
 <permission android:name="com.medicine.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.medicine.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
 <!-- This app has permission to register and receive dataf message. -->
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
 <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
 <activity android:name="com.mopub.common.MoPubBrowser" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: check your these lines :
    
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="org.pgsqlite.SQLitePlugin">
            <intent-filter />
     </activity>
    
    here you define intent filter but not any action so if you don't want to specify any action there just delete it or add any action that you want to listen,

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm getting a new error minSDKVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 8 but your answer solved my previous question. If you post this as an answer I will upvote, thanks!

Comment: increase your manifest min sdk version to 8 in manifest as well as build.gradle of app.it will resolve your problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check your these lines :

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="org.pgsqlite.SQLitePlugin">
        <intent-filter />
 </activity>
```

here you define intent filter but not any action so if you don't want to specify any action there just delete it or add any action that you want to listen,